# When do control variables increase precision?

Tags: standard-error, multicollinearity, bias, bias-variance-tradeoff, controlling-for-a-variable

Suppose we're interested in the effect $\beta$ of a treatment $D$. To increase the precision of our estimate (ie., reduce the variance of $\hat{\beta}$), we can include a control variable $X$ that explains some of the variance of $y$. Moreover, suppose the control is necessary for ruling out confounding effects from omitted variable bias. So $X$ is needed for an unbiased estimate of $\beta$, as well as possibly reducing variance.

But there seems to be a bias-variance tradeoff: as the correlation between $D$ and $X$ increases, the collinearity problem becomes bigger, meaning that there's less remaining variation in $D$ to use in estimating the treatment effect. Result: bigger standard errors and lower precision.

So it seems that control variables can increases or decrease precision, depending on the context. Can we formally characterize this relationship?

Consider the following data-generating process:
\begin{equation}
    y_{i} = \beta D_{i} + \gamma Z_{i} + e_{i}
\end{equation}

However, $Z$ is unobserved, and $\text{Cov}(D,Z) \neq 0$: we have omitted variable bias. But luckily, we have an imperfect control variable $X$ that measures $Z$ with noise: $X = Z + v$, where $v \sim N(0,\delta^{2})$. The question I want to answer is: under what conditions does controlling for $X$ reduce $\text{Var}(\hat{\beta})$? In particular, how does $\text{Var}(\hat{\beta})$ vary with the level of bias, $\text{Cov}(D,Z)$, and the strength of the control variable, measured by $\frac{1}{\text{Var}(v)}$?